# How many votes can be given to a certain user in 1 day?

Tags: discussion, voting

I remembered someone said that every user has the limitation of voting to another user. Once he/she vote up/down the same user's post more than a certain limit, the excess votes will not bring any reputation to the user. The rule will prevent anyone gaming reputation system.

But I voted up 10 times to a user (Moderator) today, I noticed that his reputation increased by 50 points.

I am confused, how many votes can be given to a certain user in 1 day?

Comment: Chris gave the correct answer. Look in his/her reputation tomorrow and most probably some or all your upvotes will "vanish".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give all your votes to a single user in one day.

However, there's a good chance that this will be spotted by various automatic processes that are on the lookout for fraudulent voting patterns and the votes will be removed.

To give **all** your votes to a single user looks like you are a sockpuppet account created by  that user to artificially boost their reputation.

Comment: It seems to me the question is asking *how many votes is too many* when it comes to tripping that fraudulent voting pattern detector. I often worry about this myself. There are some users active in the same tags as I am that give consistently awesome answers. Logically, I upvote them. Doesn't make me their sockpuppet, though. Similarly, when I come across a particularly bad question, I'll sometimes look through the user's profile to see what other questions they've asked. If they're a consistently poor question asker, I'll downvote other questions to get them one step closer to the auto-ban.

Comment: @Cody - I *think* I know, however I'm reluctant to publicise this fact. There is also a time element.

Comment: Fair enough about not wanting to publicise it. I don't think I've tripped it yet, but I don't pay close enough attention.

Answer (score 1):

Remember there is a maximum of 200 reputation points each user can gain per day (not involving points for accepted answers).